# Silencing VBA MSHTML HTMLDocument.CreateDocumentFromURL

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing some webpage parsing in VBA within Excel; I'm MSHTML to download and parse the webpage. However, on certain sites, a dialog box pops up. It works fine; however, I would like to know if there is a way to disable this or possibly get around it. Thank-you for your time. My code snippet for the document creation should be below the image.

[image: Dialog Box]

```
Dim objMSHTML As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim objDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set objDocument = objMSHTML.createDocumentFromUrl(url, "")
```

Comment: Probably your security level is too high and needs to be dropped a notch.

Comment: You could target the "x" to close with code. You don't show the HTML but it is often a possibility. It is more reactive than pro-active clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend against using MSHTML for retrieving your data from the web. You will regret it later. The reason for this is because MSHTML uses Internet Exploder in the background so you will get problems like the one you have. Another reason is because since it is using IE, it will also deal with the IE cache and you will run into problems like "I can't get updated in from the server because it's cached" or cache full errors. It may seem like that sounds rare and "it won't happen to me," you will find your life is changed into a living nightmare down the road LOL. Just my personal experience.

I recommend instead to use WinHTTP or WinInet. Just google "Winhttp vba" and you will be set.

Comment: Hmm; seems easy enough... any ideas on how to parse the HTML? How do you feel about downloading the HTML with WinHTTP and creating a MSHTML document from that text? Btw; thank-you for the information...

Comment: Well... you suggestion has kept me pushing onward. Thank-you for your assistance.